# Add Image in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

i just started to learn wxWidgets and I'm trying to create some kind of Image Opener.
But i cant understand how to add an image... 
i seen some stuff about wxImage, wxBitMap,wxStaticBitmap, but i couldn't understand any of them or the difference between them.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/filedlg.h>
#include <wx/wfstream.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
   virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
   MyFrame (const wxString& event);

   void OnOpen(wxCommandEvent& event);
   void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
   DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

DECLARE_APP(MyApp);
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
   MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame(wxT("Minimal wxWidgets App"));
   frame->Show(true);
   return true;
}

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
   EVT_MENU(wxID_OPEN, MyFrame::OnOpen)
   EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, MyFrame::OnQuit)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void MyFrame::OnOpen(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
   wxFileDialog openFileDialog(this, ("Open JPEG file"), "", "", "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*jpg", wxFD_OPEN|wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST);

   if(openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_CANCEL)
      return;

   wxFileInputStream input_stream(openFileDialog.GetPath());

   if(!input_stream.IsOk())
   {
      wxLogError("Cannot Open File '%s'.", openFileDialog.GetPath());
      return;
   }
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
   Close(true);
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{    
   wxMenuBar * menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
   wxMenu * exitMenu = new wxMenu;
   wxMenu * openMenu = new wxMenu;

   exitMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT);
   openMenu->Append(wxID_OPEN);

   menuBar->Append(openMenu, "&Open");
   menuBar->Append(exitMenu, "&Exit");

   SetMenuBar(menuBar);

   CreateStatusBar(2);
   SetStatusText(wxT("Image Opener !"));
}
```

can someone show an example of adding an image on wxwidgets ? or adding it to my code .
thanks for help !

Comment: look at the samples provides with the library. In particular check the drawing sample and of course all other.

Comment: @Igor mind to share a link ?

Comment: Just check Vadim's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxImage` is a portable representation of an image, `wxBitmap` is a platform-specific but more efficient equivalent. Generally speaking, `wxImage` is convenient for working with image data, but it needs to be converted to `wxBitmap` to be displayed.

Both of these classes are just abstract images, while `wxStaticBitmap` is a control showing an image, i.e. something you can really see on screen.

The `image` sample (under samples directory of your wxWidgets distribution) shows how to use the different classes and draw images directly.

Answer (score 0):

wxImage and wxBitmap are almost same and conversion between them is easy. wxStaticBitmap is used to display a wxBitmap.it can be done by following example(StaticBitmap1 is your wxStaticBitmap and btmp is your wxBitmap):

```
StaticBitmap1->SetBitmap(btmp);
```